# Changing the diagonals beside center diagonal of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

Is there a quick way to change the diagonals beside the center diagonal (referring to the `1`s below):

```
m =  
 2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 1     2     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     2     1     0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     2     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     1     2     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     2     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     2     1     0
 0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2     1
 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     2
```

A quick way to change the center diagonal is `m(logical(eye(size(m)))) = 2`. How about assigning the diagonals beside it to values of `1`?

Comment: By quick do you mean in terms of runtime/performance or shorter code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`diag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) function takes a second parameter, `k`, which specifies which diagonal to target:

```
diag([-1,-1,-1,-1],-1) % or diag(-1*ones(4,1),1)

ans = 

     0    0    0    0    0
    -1    0    0    0    0
     0   -1    0    0    0
     0    0   -1    0    0
     0    0    0   -1    0


diag([1,1,1,1],1)

ans = 

     0    1    0    0    0
     0    0    1    0    0
     0    0    0    1    0
     0    0    0    0    1
     0    0    0    0    0

diag([2,2,2],2)

ans = 

     0    0    2    0    0
     0    0    0    2    0
     0    0    0    0    2
     0    0    0    0    0
     0    0    0    0    0
```

If you already have an existing matrix and you want to change one of the diagonals you could do this:

```
M = magic(5) % example matrix
v = [1,2,3,4] % example vector that must replace the first diagonal of M, i.e. the diagonal one element above the main diagonal

M - diag(diag(M,1),1) + diag(v,1)
```

The idea is to first use `diag` to extract the numbers of the diagonal you want to change, `diag(M,1)`. Then to use `diag` again to change the vector that the first call to `diag` created into a matrix, `diag(diag(M,1),1)`. You'll notice that this creates a matrix with the same dimensions as `M`, the same numbers as `M` on the 1st diagonal and `0`s everywhere else. Thus `M - diag(diag(M,1),1)` just sets that first diagonal to `0`. Now `diag(v,1)` creates a matrix with the same dimensions as `M` that is `0` everywhere but with the numbers of `v` on the first diagonal and so adding `diag(v,1)` only affects that first diagonal which is all `0`s thanks to `-diag(diag(M,1),1)`

An alternative if you are just applying a constant to a diagonal (for example setting all the values on the first diagonal below the main diagonal to `6`):

```
n = 5;
k = -1;
a = 6;
M = magic(n);
ind = diag(true(n-abs(k),1),k);
M(ind) = a;
```

Comment: What if the matrix is large and you do not want to list all the ones and twos in the first parameter?

Comment: @Tyler If you just want to apply a constant to a diagonal then either use `a*ones(n,1)` or `ind = diag(true(n,1),k); M(ind) = a;` See my edits.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Took me a while to understand but I finally got it!